# Setup JAVA_HOME vs JRE_HOME vs PATH environment variables

Tags: java, variables, environment, java-home

Do I need all three environment variables if I want to compile/run or just run Java applications in linux platform?

```
JAVA_HOME   export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_75
JRE_HOME    export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_75/jre
PATH        export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.7.0_75/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't usually need `JRE_HOME` (may need to add it if other applications are looking for it, but I have never needed it). You do need `JAVA_HOME` because many applications (like Tomcat) look for this. Also, in your PATH, use `$JAVA_HOME/bin`; instead so that if you upgrade your Java, you don't have to change PATH as well :-)

Comment: From catalina.bat: `JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.`
and
`JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
                  are both set, JRE_HOME is used.`